# In NiFi how to store attribute retrieved from DB which doesn’t change very frequently?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have scheduled ExecuteSQL processor which retrieve speed limit from DB. This speed limit doesn’t change frequently so I created time interval of 24 hours. But I noticed that the next processor e.g RouteAttribute don’t store this speed limit value. With every FlowFile coming from Kafka I want to check whether speedlimit value in FlowFile is exceeding speedlimit value retrieved from DB. But value from DB gets processed as FlowFile once in 24 hours and it’s not available for comparison.

I have following flow:
1) ExecuteSQL->ConvertAvroToJson->EvaluateJsonPath-> from here I pass value of speed limit to following flow to processor RoutesAttribute.
2) ConsumeKafka->EvaluateJsonPath->RouteAttributes (RouteAtrribute get speed limit from above flow but it only gets this value once in 24 hours. How to store this value in memory permanently??)

Comment: Is there a single speedlimit, or a lot of ones (e.g. one per road)?

Comment: There he just one record which has speed limit value.

Comment: In fact SQL queryitself is - select speedlimit from ConfigTable;

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description I think this how-to HCC post is very relevant:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/140060/nifi-how-to-load-a-value-in-memory-one-time-from-c.html

In summary it leverages the fact that UpdateAttribute has a state feature and makes sure the attribute only gets updated when data is pulled in from the reference table.

---

There is also an alternate solution, if it is OK for you to restart nifi after pulling in an updated reference value, this is called the variable registry and it simplifies things a bit:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.1/bk_administration/content/custom_properties.html

Comment: Yes I have seen that HCC post earlier. I will try out UpdateAttribute processor. Thanks.